# no overload matches delegate system.speech.recognition.speechRecognizedEventargs

Tags: c#, sapi

I am working on sapi. I made a simple console application and tried to test sapi.

```
class Program
    {
        public  void abc(SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
        {
            switch (e.Result.Text)
            {
                case "say hello":
                    Console.WriteLine("Hi");
                    break;
                case "my name is irfan":
                    Console.WriteLine("hello irfan!");
                    break;
            }
        }
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SpeechRecognitionEngine sREngine = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();

            Choices com = new Choices();
            com.Add(new string[] { "say hello", "my name is irfan" });
            GrammarBuilder gb = new GrammarBuilder();
            gb.Append(com);
            Grammar gram = new Grammar(gb);
            sREngine.LoadGrammarAsync(gram);
            sREngine.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
            sREngine.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);
            sREngine.SpeechRecognized += abc; //getting error over there.

        }
    }
```

I am getting error on calling function `abc`. The error is :

"no overload matches delegate system.speech.recognition.speechRecognizedEventargs"

what I am doing wrong?

Comment: btw, you may find the code at http://SpeechTurtle.codeplex.com useful

Comment: Side note: if you'd use Visual Studio it generates delegates for you automatically when you click tab after  +=. (this comment is spam/advertisement as I work for the company that produces VS, use your best judgement when using the feature :) ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your handler signature is wrong.  It should be:

```
public void abc(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
```

Comment: Ok that worked! I am getting exception. `Additional information: An attempt has been made to free an RCW that is in use.  The RCW is in use on the active thread or another thread.  Attempting to free an in-use RCW can cause corruption or data loss.`

Comment: That's a different question.  Please don't string questions together; create another question.